# AssociatedMetadataProvider in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, modelmetadata, typedescriptor

Where I can find **AssociatedMetadataProvider** in .Net Core?
Or is there a way to implement **GetTypeDescriptor** in DefaultModelMetadataProvider?

In MVC 5 the DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider inherits from AssociatedMetadataProvider which had a method GetTypeDescriptor.

It seems this class (AssociatedMetadataProvider ) was completly removed :-(

Any advice would be very nice.

---

How I did it in Mvc 5 ?

```
    public class CustomMetadataProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ICustomTypeDescriptor GetTypeDescriptor(Type type)
    {
        if (WhatEver)
        { return new MyICustomTypeDescriptor();}
        return base.GetTypeDescriptor(type);
    }
}
```

Registration:

Global.asax

```
 ModelMetadataProviders.Current = new CustomMetadataProvider();
```

Comment: Is it just the GetTypeDescriptor method you want to use?

Comment: I want to override the GetTypeDescriptor method ;). But this Method doesn't exist anymore. And I have no idea how to implement this behaivor now.
Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.associatedmetadataprovider?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, there is no `AssociatedMetadataProvider` in .Net Core. However, they left us [`IModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.imodelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) with abstract class [`ModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that you might use, especially if you need to override some of the methods. You might also notice there is an implementation provided [`DefaultModelMetadataProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.metadata.defaultmodelmetadataprovider?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that has a method `GetMetadataForType(Type)`. It will return [`ModelMetadata`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.modelbinding.modelmetadata?view=aspnetcore-3.1) that is still not what you need. But this class has a method called `GetModelExplorerForType()` and it returns an instance of [`ModelExplorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.modelexplorer?view=aspnetcore-3.1). This instance should have all the information you need in a bit different format.
I hope it helps :)

Comment: Do you have any example code for this? I had trouble creating an instance of the DefaultmodelMetadataProvider